# Run python script when a file has been added to a folder?

Tags: python, windows, while-loop, directory

I have a folder where files are continuously added, approximately every 3 seconds. I want to create a while loop that keeps running, checking, analysing, moving and deleting files in said folder.

So far my to do list is:

1. I need to make the while loop that keeps checking the folder for new files.
2. It then has to run an analysis (a python script in a separate directory) on the new files that are added.
3. Finally it needs to move the output from the analysis, a .txt file, into a new directory, whilst the original file the analysis was run on, is deleted.

This just needs to keep running, maybe having a keybreak to stop it if needed.

I'm a total beginner at python, and this is pretty beyond my skills with while loops. I can only do very simple ones.

I've tried various things, but I'm way too inexperienced to make it work properly. Still stuck at my 1st step, just making it check the folder. Step 2 and 3 feel impossible, though I imagine it's not that difficult for people who know python.

I apologize if this is the wrong place to post this question and if I've left out important information.

If anyone has any good resources/guides/simple step-by-step I'd appreciate it!

I've tried using various suggestions I've found, they're similar questions to mine, but struggling to apply them to my problem. This is the closest I've gotten.

```
# Folder where files are added
path_to_watch = "C:/Users/Projects/main/example"

before = dict([(f, None) for f in os.listdir(path_to_watch)])
while 1:
    after = dict([(f, None) for f in os.listdir(path_to_watch)])
    added = [f for f in after if not f in before]
    if added:
        print("Added: ", ", ".join(added))
        # I think the analysis.py script has to happen somewhere here, but I don't know how to use it.
        # Then it needs to take the analysis output .txt file and move it to a new folder and delete the original file
        
        # Break Currently stops the loop after the first added file is detected. Otherwise, it keeps detecting the same 
        # file indefinitely
        break
        

    else:
        # Return to checking folder, break stops this currently
        before = after
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will resolve your problem**

```
import csv
import os
import shutil
import test_folder.test

# Folder where files are added
path_to_watch = "."

before = dict([(f, None) for f in os.listdir(path_to_watch)])
while 1:
    after = dict([(f, None) for f in os.listdir(path_to_watch)])

    added = [f for f in after if not f in before]
    if added:
        print("Added: ", ", ".join(added))
        mydir = os.getcwd() 
        mydir_new = os.chdir(mydir+"/test_folder")
        os.system('python test.py > test.log')
        shutil.move('test.log',mydir)
        break
    else:
        # Return to checking folder, break stops this currently
        before = after
```

Comment: could you explain what happens in the code you added? I'm not sure what mydir_new does. At os.system are you just telling it to run the test.py on the incoming file, naming it test.log? My analyze script already creates a named .txt file. How would I tell it to just move that?

It currently gives me the error that my destination path already exists.

Comment: mydir_new is changing the present working directory to other folder where the script exits that we need to run on the new file added.                                                                                       yes the Os.system is running the python script of the file newly added.                                       You can directly move the file to other folder , as i dont have any file i am creating a file and moving it to different folder.

Comment: Thank you so much! Very helpful :) 
Edit: 
So if the input is a .wav file, that is analysed by my pyscript and creates a new .txt file. How do I specify that I want to delete the .wav file and move the generated .txt file to a new directory? I realise you probably gave me the solution with shutil(), but I'm really bad at this. The .txt file has a new name every time, so I guess I need to tell the script to move all .txt files, though I have one exception that needs to stay in the original directory.